# How can I just import typings into Typescript, without the whole module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, npm

I am writing a piece of Express middleware in Typescript. It will be published to npm as a standalone package. I would like to be able to define my functions using Express types, as this lets me write with type safety:

```typescript
function playWithRequest( req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction ) {
    req['key'] = 'stuff';
}

module.exports = playWithRequest;
```

However, I have no need to `require('express')` itself, and I want to avoid `import` statements that will generate such a `require()` call. How can I tell Typescript about the express types without importing express itself?

The express typings are installed by `npm install @types/express`, and are thus hanging around in `node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default TypeScript will not transpile an import to require statement, which has no JS-only exports used in the compiled file.

So no require call will be generated when you only use the types exported by `@types/express`.

When you make such module ( that needs `express` only for typings ) you can safely put `@types/express` into your dependencies ( not devDependencies ) and keep `express` module inside your devDependencies ( for compilation purposes ).

By doing this whenever you install your module to your application it will be properly safe-typed but it won't complain that express is not there.